# React JS POST http://localhost:8001/calcul net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED - Back end Fastapi

Tags: python, reactjs, axios, fastapi

I have a website developed in react js on the front end. The front makes a request (POST method) to a fastapi python back end.
On the web interface, when I click on the sent button which calls the fastapi API, there is the following error:
[image]

on my local computer, everything is working fine. But when I do the production on an o2switch server, the above bug comes back.

For react js, I use axios to do the POST request:

```
Axios.post("http://localhost:8001/calcul", { 
        localisation: "MA",
        critere_priviligier: "12",
        largeur_lame: "12", espace_lame: "12"
    )
    .then(res => {
        console.log("1111", res.data);
        console.log(res)
        navigate('/response', {state: {localisation: res.data.autonomie_luminere,
                                       coefficient_cm: res.data.coefficient_cm,
                                       consommation_anuelle: res.data.consommation_anuelle,
                                       information: res.data.information,
                                       optimise: res.data.optimise}});
     
    }).
    then(function(json) {
        console.log("JSON: ", json);
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(`Error, ${error}`));
```

On fastapi, I took into account the CORS:

```
    from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
    from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
    from calcul import Calcul, CoefficientCM
    import pandas as pd

   app = FastAPI()

   origins = ["*"]

   app.add_middleware(
       CORSMiddleware,
       allow_origins=origins,
       allow_credentials=True,
       allow_methods=["*"],
       allow_headers=["*"],
   )
```

For prod, I use build folder:

```
npm run build
```

And for fastapi I use uvicorn:

```
uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8001 --reload
```

As I mentioned before, everything works fine locally. But it's when I put in production on an o2switch server that there is this bug.

**Fastapi and react js are in the same server**

Comment: Are you changing the URL you're making the request to to match the URL of where your app is hosted in production? `localhost` refers to your own computer (i.e. the computer where the _browser_ is running - that's probably not where you've hosted the API in production).

Comment: In fact, my fastapi and the react js app are hosted in the same server in production.  That's why I made localhost

Comment: Yes, but `localhost` refers to the localhost _for your browser_. Not the same host as the frontend code is delivered from.

Comment: so I have to put the external url of the server but not of the ``localhost``?

Comment: Yes, you have to use the actual URL of your service - i.e. where it can be reached on the internet. Usually you replace this in your build process when building the frontend, having one URL for local development and another URL when building for production (through environment variables or other means - exactly how depends on how you're building your production bundle.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your API_URL from localhost to URL you have on production

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).